# Sharing folders using workgroups with a Windows 7 and XP computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-sharing, file-permissions

I have two computers, one Windows 7 and one XP that I would like to share documents with over a network. I have been trying to do this by syncing their Workgroups and hoping that they would recognize each other over the network. The network group name, TESTGROUP, seems to only have the XP user while the W7 computer doesn't seem to be in a work group called TESTGROUP but rather some other work group.

I have configured the workgroup names in the System settings where it displays the specs of the computer yet I don't know why the W7 still connects do a different work group (or so it seems). I have tried mapping a network drive but to no avail.

Any help?

Comment: Have you ever messed with the homegroup settings on the 7 box?  I've had that interfere before.

Comment: Indeed I have. What do I need to do?

Comment: turn off homegroup :)

Comment: I did that and unfortunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure W7 is set to home network. You won't need the password it provides.

Then ,right click on the folder you want to share, select properties and then from the sharing tab, share it. Whilst the window is open, click on security and make sure the same rights are applied.

See if it is now visible - if not, you may have a firewall issue

Comment: I already have folders that I have enabled sharing and the security is appropriate.
I also tried disabling my firewall.

Comment: Is XP home edition? Not that it *should* matter but we have had issues with W7 and XP with XP on home

Comment: I need to go to the office to check but if it is then what should I do? Change OS?

Comment: Was it home edition?